# Export / Import Web Content in liferay

Tags: liferay

How to import / Export Web Content in liferay ?

Answer (score 3):

**Login to portal as Administrator**.
Go to Content using dockbar portlet.
Check Out the attached image. You can see settings icon on it.
**Click on it and select Import/Export**.
[Web Content Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz51G.png)

Comment: Got a reply after 5 years :D. I have switched domain and don't remember Liferay. Anyways thanks for replying hope it will be helpful to some one some day :)

Comment: Just started carrier with liferay.